# how to make a python-mysqldb template?

Tags: python, templates, mysql-python

I've learn some basics about python-mysqldb ,when I want to define anther function for query,I have to write (connect ,cursor...try ..) repeatedly
so I want to design a template like jdbcTemplate (Java EE, Spring)
my code is:

```
def DBV():
def templateFN(fn):
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
    log = logging.getLogger('DB')
    conn = MySQLdb.connect(user='root',passwd='247326',db='lucky',charset="utf8",cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor);   
    cursor = conn.cursor() 
    def wrap(data=None):
        try:
            return fn(cursor=cursor,data=data)
            #conn.commit()
        except Exception ,e: 
            conn.rollback()
            log.error('%s, transaction rollback',e)
        finally:
            cursor.close()
            conn.close()

    return wrap  
class DB():
    @templateFN
    def insertTest(self,cursor,data=None):
        data = {
                'field':'this is a test',
                'name':'this is a name'
                }
        return cursor.execute('insert into test(field,name) values(%(field)s,%(name)s)',data)
return DB()
```

db = DBV()

print 'return value',db.insertTest(data="ok")

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

File "D:\WorkSpaces\Aptana Studio 3 Workspace\VLuck\src\com\test.py", line 164, in 
    print 'return value',db.insertTest(data="ok")
TypeError: wrap() got multiple values for keyword argument 'data'

but failed,how should I do it right

Comment: some indentation may not show correctly :)

Comment: why is the "conn.commit()" only a comment?

Comment: er,I don't wanna insert it into DB for testing

Comment: How did it "fail"?  What happened?

Comment: ha, forget to post the error msg,I just edit it,please help me

Comment: all i need to do,pass the self param to ther wrap function `def wrap(self,data=None):
            try:
                return fn(self,cursor=cursor,data=data)
                #conn.commit()
            except Exception ,e: 
                conn.rollback()
                log.error('%s, transaction rollback',e)
            finally:
                cursor.close()
                conn.close()
        return wrap  `

Comment: It's called a **decorator**, not _template_, in Python.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution I came up with, inspired by [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9416947/python-class-based-decorator-with-parameters-that-can-decorate-a-method-or-a-fun):

```
def connect_mysql(func):
    # Assign value of 'self' to be default func
    func.func_defaults = func.func_defaults[:-1] + (func,)
    func._cnx = mysql.connector.connect(**CONFIG)
    func._cursor = func._cnx.cursor()
    return func

@connect_mysql
def test(data, self=None):
    self._cursor.execute("SELECT %(c1)s", data)
    print(self._cursor.fetchall())

test({'c1': 1})
```