# Decorator of classes and functions

Tags: python, class, decorator

I have a problem with a Python decorator.

```
class decorator(object):
    def __init__(self, function):
        self.function = function

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('sth to log: %s : %s' % (self.function.__name__, args))
        return self.function(*args, **kwargs)


@decorator
def sum_test(a, b):
    print('sum: %s' % (a+b))

@decorator
class Class_test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def sum_func(self, a, b):
        print('class sum: %s' % (a+b))
        return a+b

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sum_test(3, 4)
    func = Class_test()
    var1 = func.sum_func(1, 4)
    print(var1)
```

Output:

```
sth to log: sum_test : (3, 4)
sum: 7
sth to log: Class_test : ()
class sum: 5
5
```

The decorator is working as I want for function `sum_test`. I can log that function `sum_test` was used with variables `3` and `4`.

I have a problem with decorating classes. I can log that object of class `Class_test` was created, but I don't have information that function `sum_func` was used.

Why is `__call__()` in decorator was not triggered when running `sum_func` on class object and it was triggered when used directly on function `sum_test`?

Comment: **Side Note:** I recommend using closures inside of functions instead of a full-blown **class**.

Comment: What do you want the decorator to do when applied on a class? Is it meant to decorate every method of the class?

Comment: Generally speaking you can't apply the same decorator to both functions and classes—although it might be possible with some clever coding.

Comment: I want to have decorator with logging which functions and classes where used with variables. Should I have another decorator for class? Could I have another decorator only for function of class sum_func?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decorating the class with `decorator` means that `Class_test` is now a `decorator` object such that `Class_test.function` is the class you wrote a body for.

Remember, the `@decorator` syntax is syntactic sugar for

```
class Class_test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def sum_func(self, a, b):
        print('class sum: %s' % (a+b))
        return a+b

Class_test = decorator(Class_test)
```

(Except that at no point does the `Class_test` symbol refer to your class).

So this `decorator` object is called when you call `Class_test`, which is exactly what you see happen in your log:

```
sth to log: Class_test : ()
```

`func.sum_func`, on the other hand, is a regular bound method.  It doesn't know anything about `decorator`.

If you're going to use it inside classes, I would prefer a closure-style decorator (a function that returns a function).  The function that it returns will get registered a a method normally by the `class` machinery.

```
from functools import wraps

def decorator(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print('sth to log: %s : %s' % (func.__name__, args))
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

class Class_test(object):
    @decorator
    def sum_func(self, a, b):
        print('class sum: %s' % (a+b))
        return a+b
```

If you still want to use the class-based approach, read [Python Class Based Decorator with parameters that can decorate a method or a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9416947/python-class-based-decorator-with-parameters-that-can-decorate-a-method-or-a-fun)

Comment: Should I have different decorator for class?

I have issue when decorating directly function in the class:
 return self.function(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: sum_func() missing 1 required positional argument: 'b'

How to tell decorator to return function to that class?

Comment: @Pablo I added a section to my answer to address that.