# Using a context manager as a global dependency in Fast API

Tags: python, fastapi, httpx

I have a FastAPI app that mostly calls external apis. In some instances, a path operation will make several calls to the same host. For that reason, I want to use a single httpx AsyncClient for each request.

The correct way to do this seems to be yielding the client within a depepdency:

```
async def get_client(token: str):

    client = httpx.AsyncClient(headers={"Authorization": f"Bearer {token}"})
    
    try:
        yield client
    
    finally:
        await client.aclose()
```

I do not want to add this dependency to every path operation though, purely for the sake of not repeating myself throughout the code. However, having read https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/global-dependencies/, it seems global dependencies are only applicable if that dependency is doing something, rather than returning something. I cannot see how each path operation accesses the yielded client unless the dependency is specified explicitly for that particular path operation. I also cannot see how to pass the token to the dependency.

i.e. this will not allow my path operations to use the client:

```
app.include_router(
    router,
    prefix="/api",
    dependencies=Depends(get_client)
)
```

but this will:

```
@router.get("/", status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK)
async def get_something(request: Request, client: httpx.AsyncClient = Depends(get_client)):

    client.get('www.google.com')
```

Is it possible to use global dependencies if that dependency returns something that is required by the path operation?

Comment: As workaround, you could use [class based views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63853813/how-to-create-routes-with-fastapi-within-a-class)

Comment: Where does the token come from? You could also use the `state` object present on the request object to store a reference there, but `Depends` usually works fine (the `get_client` can in turn have a dependency on `get_current_token` or something like that)

Answer (score 0):

I am under the impression that FastAPI dependencies are not the right for this class of problems. I neither want class based views (as suggested in the comments), nor do I want to add a repetitive parameter to all routes. Instead, I will just use a global httpx client instance that can be imported everywhere needed.

So I created a module `http` which exports `get()` and `post()` functions. As well as closing all connections via `.aclose()` when the FastAPI shuts down.

```py
from httpx import AsyncClient

from .app import app


async def get(*args, **kwargs):
    return await HTTPX_CLIENT.get(*args, **kwargs)


async def post(*args, **kwargs):
    return await HTTPX_CLIENT.post(*args, **kwargs)


@app.on_event("shutdown")
async def shutdown_event():
    await HTTPX_CLIENT.aclose()


HTTPX_CLIENT = AsyncClient()
```

so that any route can import it and make requests using that single httpx client:

```py
from .http import post


@app.get("/")
async def root():
    await post('http://host', json=dict(hello="world"))
    return {"message": "I just posted!"}
```

Comment: FastAPI does support a global dependency but it is unclear to me from the docs how an api function can then access this value https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/global-dependencies/