# Fastapi Dependency Injection with CLI Arguments

Tags: python, dependencies, singleton, fastapi

I want my fastapi routes to include a dependency injection formed from the parameters of a CLI.

In the skeleton code below, a, b and c are the CLI parameters, Consort is the DI and the fastapi class is King.

How can this be achieved?

```
import charles, william, george #program modules

from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends
       
    app = FastAPI() 
    
    class Consort:
        def __init__(self, a, b, c):
            self.x = a_stuff(a)
            self.y = b_stuff(b)
            self.z = c_stuff(c)
    
    class King:
        def __init__(self, a, b, c):
            ... ...
    
        @router.post("/create")
        async def create(self, consort=Depends(Consort())):
            return charles.create()
    
        @router.post("/read")
        async def read(self, consort=Depends(Consort())):
            return william.read()
    
        @router.post("/update")
        async def update(self, consort=Depends(Consort())):
            return george.update()
    
        @router.post("/delete")
        async def delete(self, consort=Depends(Consort())):
            return elizabeth.delete()
    
    def main(args):
        a, b, c = arg_parse()
        service = King(a, b, c)
        uvicorn.run(... ... ...)
        return
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main(sys.argv)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Question is in the preamble ie. How is fastapi initiated with the Consort dependency injection which uses the a, b and c parameters?

Comment: Are you trying to configure a FastAPI app using a CLI?

Comment: The CLI module calls the main (fastapi) module with subprocess.run(["python", "main.py", "-arguments", params], text=True) with params holding the parameters a, b and c

Comment: I suggest you re-read FastAPI’s documentation on `Depends`. It requires a callable (e.g. `Consort`) not a class instance (e.g. `Consort()`). Also, you can’t use `@router` on a class method as explained in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63853813/how-to-create-routes-with-fastapi-within-a-class/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you're after is you want to be able to pass `a`, `b,` and `c` into your constructor, use those to construct a `Consort`, and then be able to access that `Consort` instance in your routes. With [classy-fastapi](https://pypi.org/project/classy-fastapi/) I think you can do what you want with something like:

```py
from classy_fastapi import Routable, post
import charles

class Consort:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.x = a_stuff(a)
        self.y = b_stuff(b)
        self.z = c_stuff(c)

class King(Routable):
    def __init__(self, consort):
        super().__init__()
        self.consort = consort

    @post("/create")
    async def create(self):
        return charles.create(self.consort)

def main(args):
    a, b, c = arg_parse()
    consort = Consort(a, b, c)
    service = King(consort)
    uvicorn.run(... ... ...)
    return
```

Note that unlike the `Depends` way of doing things you do not inject into individual methods. Instead, you inject, via the constructor, into the class that holds the routes.

Full disclosure: I'm the author of `classy-fastapi`.

Comment: Thanks. 'charles, 'william', etc. are imported modules (question updated). So, for example, I want to pass the DI Consort like charles.create(consort).

Comment: @HenryThornton edited. I think it solves your problem now.